# Hierarchical copula vs. vine copula

Tags: statistics, correlation, statistical-finance, copula, dependence

**Vine copulas** are a sequential cascade of bivariate copulas meant to capture the hierarchical structure in the dependence structure of random variables. How does this relate or differ from the concept of **hierarchical copulas**?

In *Dynamic copula methods in finance*, hierarchical copulas are premised on the fact that

> The dependence structure of variables of the same group (in a parallel with econometrics, we could call it *within dependence*) is higher than that of variables of different groups (*between dependence*).

but no comparison is made between vine and hierarchical copulas, even both seem to capture hierarchical structure.